# Personal project: using while loops

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I am new to PHP. I am trying to create a simple personal project where several coins move around the page when users refresh it from their browser. I keep on getting a weird error ([image: see attachment]).
This is what my file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Treasure Map</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image:url(Bluemap.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat">

            <?php
        $numberOfCoins = rand(3, 10);

        while ($numberOfCoins) {
            $xPosition = rand("10", "650");
            $yPosition = rand("10", "400");
            print '<div style="position: absolute;';
            print 'left:' . $xPosition . 'px;';
            print 'top:' . $yPosition . 'px">';
            print '<img src="goldCoin.png" height="50px"/>';
            print '</div>';
            $numberOfCoins--;
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Save the page as `.php` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The file is an HTML document, therefore it cannot run PHP code.

You need to rename it from index3.html to index3.php and also make sure you are running it on a server that runs PHP

Comment: Your right. Thank you. Guess I'll loose points for that on this forum. :(

Comment: However, if a HTML document cannot read PHP code then how can HTML documents contain PHP tags around HTML code in it and it executes fine in the browser? Am I mistaken in believing this? For example, I have seen people creating forms in HTML files where they tag contain HTML markup with PHP tags. Is this something different? My apologies for my naivety.

Comment: @greg You can have html code inside a php file just make sure that your html tags are outside the opening and closing php tags

Answer (score 0):

You should save the file as .php. This just shows the code itself, which means that it is not parsed.

Apart from that, your code is slightly off too.

The variable `$numberOfCoins` now contains a random number between 3 and 10. If you want to iterate a random number of times, an if loop might be more convenient:

```
$numberOfCoins = rand(3,10);

for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfCoins; $i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Why a for loop? I can use multiple solutions for this problem (while loop, do-while loop, etc). I understand there are pros and cons for both. How is a for loop give a distinct advantage?

Comment: You can use a while-loop, but you're just iterating infinitely over a variable containing a random number. You could do something like: while($numberOfCoins > 0), but you'd have to manually decrease the value of $numberOfCoins in every iteration.